# Issue with Program that builds strings

Tags: java, logic, stringbuilder

I wrote a program that performs certain operations (AND, OR, NOR, NAND, NOT, XOR) on two binary numbers and returns the result. I used a stringbuilder to produce the result. The program's method uses a for loop to look through each character in BinaryA (because they both have the same length) and then uses an algorithim based on a truth table to get the result.

The only issue i'm having is that the result keeps outputting either 00000000 or 11111111 as a result. I'm not sure what my logic issue is:

```
public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String Operator = "AND";
    String binA = "10110101";
    String binB = "00110001";

    System.out.println(Operator + " and binary numbers " + binA + " and " + binB + " result in the output " + doOperation(Operator, binA, binB));

}

public static StringBuilder doOperation(String Operator, String BinaryA, String BinaryB)
{
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 0; i < BinaryA.length(); i++)
    {
        if(Operator.equals("AND"))
        {
            if(BinaryA.equals("1") && BinaryB.equals("1"))
                result.append('1');
            else
                result.append('0');
        }
        else if (Operator.equals("OR"))
        {
            if(BinaryA.equals("0") && BinaryB.equals("0"))
                result.append('0');
            else
                result.append('1');

        }
        else if (Operator.equals("NAND"))
        {
            if(BinaryA.equals("1") && (BinaryB.equals("1")))
                result.append('0'); 
            else
                result.append('1');
        }
        else if (Operator.equals("NOR"))
        {
            if(BinaryA.equals("0") && (BinaryB.equals("0")))
                result.append('1');
            else
                result.append('0');
        }
        else if (Operator.equals("XOR"))
        {
            if(BinaryA.equals("1") && BinaryB.equals("0") || (BinaryA.equals("0")) && BinaryB.equals("1"))
                result.append('1');
            else
                result.append('0');

        }
    }
    return result;

}

}
```

OUTPUT:
AND and binary numbers 10110101 and 00110001 result in the output 00000000

Comment: Parsing them as numbers would be a lot more efficient and less error-prone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This won't work, `BinaryA` and `BinaryB` are `String`s, but you want to compare individual `char`s:

```
if (BinaryA.equals("1") && BinaryB.equals("1"))
```

Instead, you should do a char-by-char traversal, something like this:

```
if (BinaryA.charAt(i) == '1' && BinaryB.charAt(i) == '1')
```

Change all the comparisons so they operate on the single `char` pointed by the current `i` index.

Comment: Perfect!!!!! I made Such a silly mistake, but it happens to the best of us I suppose.

Answer (score 2):

You should try this :

```
if(Operator.equals("AND"))
    {
        if(BinaryA.charAt(i)=='1'&&  BinaryB.charAt(i)=='')
            result.append('1');
        else
            result.append('0');
    }
    else if (Operator.equals("OR"))
    {
        if(BinaryA.charAt(i)=='0' && BinaryB.charAt(i)=='0')
            result.append('0');
        else
            result.append('1');

    }
```

Comment: you are right but i think is 1 not 0, any way. you are welcomed @c0der!